# MFRC522 taking too long time to read a NTAG213 in my code but in other code it's fast

Tags: python, nfc, rfid, mifare

So I wrote a code for my final project, in the beginning, it's okay to read NTAG213. But now it's taking too long time for reading NTAG213. I thought that my MFRC522 may be broke, but when I tried to run it in several code, NTAG213 can be read as fast as it was before. But when I run it again in my code, it can't be read yet or taking time too long.

I was comparing my code with any other code and add:

```
    self.MFRC522(self.RFCrgReg, (0x07<<4))
```

to my MFRC522.py, but it's not change anything and my tag still can't be read and sometimes taking time too long. And here's my main code. in main.py:

```
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import database
    import MFRC522
    import MySQLdb as mariadb

    db = database.cb()

    def connect():
        return mariadb.connect(user='root', passwd='root', host='127.0.0.1', db='pydb')

    class Actions:
          incoming=1
          outcoming=2

    #for read RFID Tag
    def ntag213():
        reading = True
        while reading:
              mifare = MFRC522.MFRC522()
              (status, TagType) = mifare.MFRC522_Request(mifare.PICC_REQIDL)
              if status == mifare.MI_OK:
                 print('Card Identified')
              (status, backData) = mifare.MFRC522_Anticoll()
              if status == mifare.MI_OK:
                 print 'TagID : '+str(backData[0])+'.'+str(backData[1])+'.'+str(backData[2])+'.'+str(backData[3])
              mifare.AntennaOff()
              reading = False
              return str(backData[0])+str(backData[1])+str(backData[2])+str(backData[3])
```

or you can visit https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sbPyiKOCWsp5mpDRPu0HQ-yaW-D0D0P3 for all code.
Thankyou so much. Please help me.

Comment: First thing I noticed: your `while` loop will never loop. The last two lines will independently end it on the first iteration.

Comment: Thankyou for ur response, so i tried to erase `mifare.AntennaOff()` and it works. Such a shame for me. Thanku again @KlausD.